# Is the Ring of Integers of A Number Field a GCD Domain? The Ring of S-Integers?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be an arbitrary number field. I know that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a Dedekind domain. I know that it need not be a PID. However, despite a long search, I am having a hard time finding either an affirmative or negative answer to the question of whether $\mathcal{O}_K$ is necessarily a GCD domain. If anyone knows the answer to this question, then please let me know.

I also have a related question: Let $S$ be any finite set of places of $K$ that contains all the Archimedian places. Let $\mathcal{O}_{K, S}$ be the ring of $S$-integers of $K$; that is, the set of all $x \in K$ such that for each place $v \notin S,$ we have $|x|_v \leq 1.$ Is $\mathcal{O}_{K, S}$ necessarily a GCD domain?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Being a localization of $O_K$, $O_{K,S}$ is a Dedekind domain and its ideal class group is the quotient of $C_K$ by the classes of the primes in $S$. Iff $S$ contains enough primes to generate $C_K$ then $O_{K,S}$ is a PID

Comment: @reuns Thank you!

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I do not understand your second comment. Also, could you please tell me by which multiplicatively closed set the ring of S-integers is a localization of the ring of integers? Thanks!

Comment: See also [this Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2892565/3111) to a previous Question with a related but somewhat different focus.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks!

Comment: My comment holds at least if $S$ contains all or none of the prime ideals above $p$ : if $S$ contains all the prime ideals above $p \in \Bbb{Z}$ then $O_{K,S}$ contains $p^{-1}$ so it is clear every ideal of $O_K$ of norm a power of $p$ becomes trivial in $O_{K,S}$. If $S$ contains only one prime ideal above $p$ and that it is not principal then it is more complicated

Comment: @reuns I see; thank you. Also, is it a localization by powers of a single element, as in the case of K = \Q ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Dedekind domain $D$ is Noetherian so atomic, i.e. nonunits $\neq 0$ factor into atoms = irreducibles.

Thus $D$ is a GCD domain $\iff D$ is a UFD, by the same proof as in $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ i.e. gcds exist [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) Euclid's Lemma holds, which implies atoms are prime.

$D$ Dedekind [$\Rightarrow D$ is $1$-dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98026/242) (prime ideals $\!\neq\! 0$ are max), [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12829/242) $D$ is a UFD $\!\iff\! D$ is a PID.

Hence a Dedekind domain $D$ is a GCD domain $\iff D$ is a UFD $\iff D$ is a PID.